# rosbag doesn't playback at same speed

Tags: rosbag, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have recorded a rosbag w topics at ~7 Hz. When I use `rosbag play` on those topics, they playback at 2Hz. The `rosbag info` too shows a total time of say 10 secs for instance but on playing it, it goes on for much more than 10 seconds.

Any tools you would recommend for me to debug without having to go through the code?

Thank you

edit 1: turns out it's `image_view` that I'm running which slows it down. Is this a known problem that image_view doesn't show images at ~7Hz at 3MP?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276127/rosbag-doesn%27t-playback-at-same-speed/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out to be a decompression issue. I had compressed bags that were unable to decompress and play at the desired frequency of the messages. Using `rosbag decompress` on these before playing them does the trick.

I didn't initially know of the `decompress` tool in rosbag so I was re recording the messages (at the slow speed) into another bag and playing that. But that seemed to do some unnatural behavior. Firstly the bags were much longer (which makes sense due to the slow speed) but then using the `--clock` option didn't make them use the time that was on the messages. They would still use the computer time.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2017-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0